# Highcharts.JS deleting data and freezing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm retrieving data from Firebase RealTime Database. I need to get the values in a chart so I decided to use highchart.js.
Could someone please explain to me why the oldest values in my chart are getting deleted? I use highcharts stocks. I tried to add a scroll bar so I can see all the values but it's not working.
I also don't understand why my browser is freezing when I load the chart... I do think it's because I load the chart when I'm refreshing the browser but it's weird because I only show 200 values at most for now.

Thanks a lot !

Code in main.js :

```
     // function to plot values on charts
function plotValues(chart, timestamp, value) {
    var x = epochToJsDate(timestamp).getTime();
    var y = Number(value);
    if (chart.series[0].data.length > 40) {
        chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, false, true); //If you want a point limit: 1) Change the "40" to the limit you want and put "true" instead of "false
    } else {
        chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, false, true);
    }

    chartALM = createALMChart();
    
     dbRef.orderByKey().on('child_added', snapshot => {
                    var jsonData = snapshot.toJSON(); 
                    // Save values on variables
                    var Défaut_communication_automate = jsonData.Défaut_communication_automate;
                    var timestamp = jsonData.timestamp;
                    // Plot the values on the charts
                    plotValues(chartALM, timestamp, Défaut_communication_automate);
                    });

   

Code in charts-definition.js :

    // Create the charts when the web page loads
    window.addEventListener('load', onload);    
    
    function onload(event) {
        chartALM = createALMChart();
    // Create ALM Chart
    function createALMChart() {
        
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart-ALM',
                type: 'spline'
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled: true,
                height: 100,
                allButtonsEnabled: true,
                buttons: [{
                   {
                    type: 'year',
                    count: 1,
                    text: 'Week',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: true,
                        units: [['week', [1]]]
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'Month',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: true,
                        units: [['month', [1]]]
                    }
                }],
                buttonTheme: {
                    width: 60
                },
                selected: 2
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'ALM',
                
                showInNavigator: true
            },{
                name: 'ATRE'
            }],
            title: {
                text: undefined
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                   
                },
                line: {
                    animation: false,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: { second: '%H:%M:%S' },
                scrollbar: {
                    enabled: true
                  }
    
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Défaut communication automate'
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: true
            }
        });
        return chart;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide what your plotValues() function looks like?

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. I assumed you have the third property of addPoint set to true and it was the reason for data deletion (as expected in the comment), but now I'm confused.

I've reproduced your example to the working demo https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6xq48mtz/ and don't see any problems on the highcharts side, so the problem has to be due to the wrong firebase configuration.

I suppose this is not a full config, could you provide it? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: When I start sending the data and the curve is created, I have no problems. My curve plots well like your snippet. The problem occurs when I refresh the tab, it crashes the tab even if there are only 60-70 points. I have no error with the plot of the curve. The only errors I have are related to data that I am displaying on another page. Being in the same js, I have these errors when displaying the web page.

Comment: Try the following code in your plotValues() and let me know if it helped `if (chart.series[0].options.data.length > 40) {
  chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], false, false);
  chart.redraw();
} else {
  chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], false, true);
  chart.redraw();
}`

Comment: Hi ! It does not trace the curves at all

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, my bad (the shift parameter should be false). Please try again with this code:
`if (chart.series[0].options.data.length > 40) {   chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], false, false);   chart.redraw(); } else {   chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], false, false);   chart.redraw(); }`

Comment: I thought about it and tried to put in false. However, it didn't change anything, I still have the freeze after I refresh the tab. I sincerely thank you for the time you take to help me.

Comment: I'm afraid that without a full config or working demo I am not able to help you more. So far, I don't find anything that would indicate the HC issue. I would also suggest adding the [firebase] tag - if the issue occurs due to Firebase configuration

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help and the time you gave me. I can give you the total configuration but the code is a bit long (if you don't mind) and I could give you the identifiers in private message if you allow me. It's a "learning" project so it's not "confidential" data, I could start the project again with different auths

Comment: Hi, just one more idea for checking. If you're using Highstock the `series.dataGrouping` is set to the true by the default. Try to change it to false. If it doesn't help, please reproduce your example to the jsfiddle (just pull out data that you're getting in your database and provide in HC config you use)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to freezing the browser, try to close your `onload()` function and then add the `createALMChart()` function.

```
function onload(event) {
    chartALM = createALMChart();
}

function createALMChart() {  
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
       (...)
    });
    return chart;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to put the closing bracket for the onload function. It was already like the code you sent me when I asked why it was freezing. Thank you for your answer. I did an edit to give you my plotValues() function.